# Mongodb multilingual query

Tags: mongodb

Material collection represents user submissions. 
Default language is defined by the user. Other users can extend first submission with some other languages.

When I request a material, maybe I need more than one language, so I think it fits ok with just one collection where I should support multilanguage.

My current desing is like this (document for testing):

```
   {
    "activities": [ "Ficha de actividades", "Juego Colectivo" ], 
    "files": [ "Asociacion_Profesiones.zip"], 
    "areas": ["Literatura", "Ciencias Naturales", "Ciencias Sociales" ], 
    "authors": [
        { "author": "César", "email": "xxx@gmail.com"}, 
        { "author": "José", "email": "xxxx@gmail.com"}
    ], 
    "desc": "La leche, el agua, el vino y la bebida", 
    "state":  1, 
    "date": ISODate("2017-01-10 19:40:39"),
    "updated": null, 
    "id": 1, 
    "language": "spanish",
    "images": [], 
    "license": "Creative Commons BY-NC-SA", 
    "downloads": 0, 
    "popular": false, 
    "title": "La bebida", 
    "file": "1.zip",
    "translations": [
       {"language": "english", "title": "Beverages", "desc": "Milk, water, wine and all related with drinking", "authors": [], "files": [], "file": "1.zip", "images": [], "downloads": 0, "state": 1, "created": null,  "updated": null},
       {"language": "french", "title": "le boisson", "desc": "du lait, de l'eau, du vin, boire", "authors": [], "files": [], "file": "1.zip", "images": [], "downloads": 0, "state": 1, "created": null,  "updated": null} 
    ]
```

}

I create a text index focused on title and descripcion (desc) fields.

```
db.materials.createIndex({ "title": "text", "desc": "text", "translations.title": "text", "translations.desc": "text"})
```

I know the user default language, but I don't know how he should make the search.
Imagine an spanish user want to search for drinks:

```
db.materials.find( { $text: { $search: "drink", $language: "es"} } ).explain(true)
```

It returns our document. It searches drink, and as "Milk, water, wine and all related with drinking" has drink as stemming for drinking it works ok.

However... if I look for water:

```
db.materials.find( { $text: { $search: "water", $language: "es"} } ).explain(true)
```

It returns nothing. water gets converted to wat (as spanish verbs end with er suffix) and "wat" is not found.

Any improvement to my searches?

The only workaround I can imagine is to add language dropdown selector to user searches.

Comment: You are searching the Spanish text using English words?

Comment: I'm searching in the user's profile default language. What I would like is to prevent failures if the user wants to search in another language.

Comment: Then I think they would have to select the language they want to search in unless you can infer what language they want to use based on their search term

Comment: even that way, maybe the word user is looking in spanish, is not found, but a world spelling similar exists in english or french subdocument and the query returns that document.